# Permissions in smb4k mounts

Tags: kde, samba

I use Smb4K for mounting my shares across my machines. However, something's happened, and when I mount my NAS share on my laptop I can't write to the share unless I `sudo` to root.

According to top, Smb4K runs under my user account. Smb4k's settings for user and group are 1000 and the file and dir masks are `0755`, and write access is set to "read-write". However, when it mounts the device to `/media/nasbox/fileshare`, the `nasbox` folder is created under the user account, but the `fileshare` folder was created under the root account.

When I unmount, both `nasbox` and `fileshare` are removed from the filesystem.

Whilst mounted, if I try to `chown` the `fileshare` to the user account, it says success, but doesn't actually change.

Does anyone know how I can fix the permissions to write normally?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

This is what I did to fix it:

1. `sudo apt-get --purge remove smb4k`
2. I went to the root folder and looked for leftover smb4k files with `sudo find -name "smb4k"`
3. I removed the smb4k folder in /.local/share/
4. I removed the smb4k file in the subfolder "Lintian/override"
5. I installed smb4k again with  `sudo apt-get install smb4k`

Now it mounts the smb shares as it should, with permissions for my standard user.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I fell into this problem too. 
I went to the folder indicated in
the [answer by @gefeba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481299/377345)
and I saw the files. 
In the file `custom_options.xml`,
there are four parameters that were wrong:

```
<gid> 0 </gid>
<group> root </group>
<uid> 0 </uid>
<owner> root </owner>
```

I changed it to:

```
<gid> 1000 </gid>
<group> gabriel </group>
<uid> 1000 </uid>
<owner> gabriel </owner>
```

Close the application and open it again.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these are working for me.  *Editing the `custom_options.xml` doesn't because it doesn't exist in either of those folders, hence I can't actually edit it.  If I create it myself, which folder should it be in, and what should it's permissions be set to?*

edit:  it's created when setting custom option in the GUI.  Unfortunately, the above fix didn't work for me

edit2:  figured it out:  make sure "This server supports CIFS Unix extensions" is OFF, either in the UI, or in `custom_options.xml` as:  `<cifs_unix_extensions_support>0</cifs_unix_extensions_support>`